# Show that Z(7)\0 under modular multiplication is isomorphic to C(6)

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

**The problem:**

I have (G, *) = (Z(7)\0, multiplication under modular arithmetic)

Specifically: G = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

I'm supposed to show that G is isomorphic to C(6) (the cyclic group with 6 elements).

**This means that I need to show:**

1. There is a generator x with the order 6
2. There is a bijection f: G -> C(6) such that f(x*x') = f(x) + f(x) where * is the operation for G and + is the operation for C(6).

**What I'm wondering about:**

Is G = <3> (that is: is 3 a generator for G?)

I think it is, since 3 repeatedly multiplied with itself gives the series:

3,2,6,4,5,1

How exactly do you prove a bijection like that? Especially, how do you manipulate the RHS? Are there specific rules for + that hold that doesn't hold for groups?

Do you do something like:

f(x*x') = f(3^x * 3^x') = f(3^(x+x')) = ... something here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really done. Proving that $\Bbb Z_7\setminus\{0\}$ is generated by $3$, you've shown that it is cyclic and has $6$ elements, and therefore must be isomorphic to $C_6$. You don't need to say more.

If you *want* to say more, let $f:\Bbb Z_7\setminus\{0\} \to C_6$ be the homomorphism with $f(3) = g$, where $g\in C_6$ is a generator of the cyclic group. Then we must have $f(2) = g^2$, $f(6) = g^3$, $f(4) = g^4$, $f(5) = g^5$ and $f(1) = g^6 = e$. It's rather easy to verify that this is indeed a homomorphism, although to make the workload lighter, it's probably best to rewrite $2 = 3^2, 6 = 3^3$ and so on. Then you can just point out that $f(3^i\cdot 3^j) = f(3^{i+j}) = g^{i+j} = g^i\cdot g^j = f(3^i)\cdot f(3^j)$, and you don't have to verify one entry at the time in the multiplication table..

Comment: Wow! Your example in the 2nd paragraph really sorted out how one might go about proving that a bijection between the two exists, thank you! You write "homomorphism" there though, did you mean isomorphism? I don't know what a homomorphism is yet, unfortunately. Regardless, thank you, I really get what's going on now.

Comment: @ejbs No, I meant homomorphism. A homomorphism is a function that covers the "such that f(x*x') = f(x) + f(x) where * is the operation for G and + is the operation for C(6)" part of your ismomorphism definition. In other words, it's like an isomorphism, but without the requirement that it be bijective (homomorphisms need not be neither injective nor surjective, but they must respect the group operation in this way).

Comment: @ejbs And seriously, you've covered isomorphisms, but not mentioned homomorphisms? That's just strange.

Comment: @Arthur Depending on the textbook, this is not 'that' strange. For instance, Gallian defines isomorphism before homomorphism in order to place emphasis on things that are 'the same' before talking about things that are only 'similar' - in the context of identifying things with their homomorphic image.